# how to validate error in specific element or fields - Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

please give some idea how to put error in specific element/field in Codeigniter..

like this:
[image]

Comment: Have you read and understood the [documentation](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html) regarding field validation?

Comment: echo form_error( 'yourFieldName' );

Comment: Can you explain this more

Answer (score 0):

**In View-Form**

```
<?php echo form_label('Student Email :'); ?> <?php echo form_error('semail'); ?>
<?php echo form_input(array('id' => 'demail', 'name' => 'semail')); ?>
```

**In Controller**

```
$this->load->library('form_validation');
// Validation For Email Field
$this->form_validation->set_rules('semail', 'Email', 'required|valid_email');
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
{
    $this->load->view('formview');
}
else
{
    $this->load->view('homeview');
}
```

[CodeIgniter Form Validation Example](http://www.formget.com/form-validation-using-codeigniter/)

Comment: Did you check this??